# 'Media not found' when trying to play video

Tags: java, android

I have a weird problem, I am playing a video file from local storage, if the video name is "test#.mp4" it does not work and shows "media not found" toast, if it's "test.mp4", it works fine, no idea where is the problem.
basically if the name has "#" anywhere, the video does not play.
Here is my code

```
String item = names.get(itemPosition); // file name eg. test#.mp4
Uri uri  = Uri.parse(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles/"+item); // path to file
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Since Android 7/N you should use a FileProvider to serve your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I needed to use FileProvider, I have no idea why my earlier method was working and sometimes not.Also because the original documentation is so confusing, I used this answer, I took a look at the actual Uri and everything made sense now! [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)